# Delete User: The directory service can perform the requested operation only on a leaf object

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I have a vb page to search for a specified user in Active Directory and delete this.
This script has allways runned fine. But now I receive an error for some users:

```
The directory service can perform the requested operation only on a leaf object
```

I found out that this happens only for users which have the *ExchangeActiveSyncDevices* attribute under their AD account. The users which don't have this attribute are still removed succesfully.
This attribute is added for iphone sync.
Is there a way to force the delete and ignore the child objects? Or how can I delete this accounts?

Comment: This may help as it works for both user and computer objects in AD: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285039/the-directory-service-can-perform-the-requested-operation-only-on-a-leaf-object

Answer (score 0):

To delete an object and all subordinate objects, use the subtree delete control, if supported by the LDAP directory server. See this [blog entry](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/ldap-subtree-delete-control/).