# The directory service can perform the requested operation only on a leaf object. computerprincipal

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

Im using the below code to delete computer from AD

```
            using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, null, null))
            {
                var computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, computerName);

                if (computer != null)
                    computer.Delete();
            }
```

Im getting below error
"**The directory service can perform the requested operation only on a leaf object**."
Please help

Answer (score 5):

This answer is a bit late, but to add on Brian's answer.

This is how you can access `DeleteTree()`

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, null, null))
{
   var computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, computerName);
   if (computer != null)
   {
      DirectoryEntry en = computer.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
      en.DeleteTree();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means there's something below the computer in the tree - probably something like a shared printer that's published to the directory. AD treats deleting an object differently than deleting an object with children.

As it doesn't look like `ComputerPrincipal` gives you a native option to delete the subtree, do something like `computer.GetUnderlyingObject().DeleteTree()` and you should be good.

Comment: there is no DeleteTree function for GetUnderlyingObject()

Comment: Hi Brian,please lemme know how to delete leaf objects

Answer (score 0):

```
((DirectoryEntry)computer.GetUnderlyingObject()).DeleteTree();
```

That's what you're looking for Shiv455